# Young's convolution inequality for weak $L^p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Young's convolution inequality is very famous:
$$
\|f\ast g\|_{L^r} \le C_{p,q,r} \|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}} \|g\|_{L^q},
$$
for any $p,q,r \in (1,\infty)$ such that $1/p + 1/q = 1/r + 1$.

I wonder if we can choose $p=1$; that is, the estimate like
$$
\|f\ast g\|_{L^r} \le C_{q,r} \|f\|_{L^{1,\infty}} \|g\|_{L^q}
$$
holds?

Answer (score 1):

If $p=1,$ then $q=r.$ The inequality fails for $q=r=2.$ Consider $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}).$ Then for $f\ge 0$  the norm of the convolution operator with $f$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is equal $\|f\|_{L^1}.$ Indeed, the convolution operator is unitarily equivalent to multiplication operator by $\widehat{f}(t)=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty f_ne^{int}$ on the space $L^2(-\pi,\pi).$ The norm of the latter coincides with the maximal value of $|\widehat{f}|,$ which is equal $\widehat{f}(0)=\|f\|_{L^1}.$ The inequality would imply that this norm is bounded above by  $C \|f\|_{L^{(1,\infty)}}.$ This is impossible as the spaces $L^1$ and $L^{(1,\infty)}$ are different. The inequality fails also for $r=q>1.$ Indeed,
by the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem the norm of the same convlution operator with symmetric ($f(n)=f(-n)$) positive function $f$ is  greater or equal to this norm on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z}).$  Actually the operator norm is again equal $\|f\|_{L^{1}}.$ The above remains  true for any topological abelian group $G,$ for example $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{T},$ with the same proof, where the duality between $G$ and the group of its characters $\Gamma.$